# How to handle sessions with QuickBlox in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, quickblox

I am using Quickblox example writing in Swift for chat app. It uses QMServices.

Questions:
1) is there any approach for user login in iOS application with some session_token generated in any cloud backend ?
2) please help - how to renew user sessions in right way, I always get 422 error (validation error) multiple times (

In app using QuickBlox for iOS I try to login user in appdelegate:

```
    if Storage.sharedInstance.currentUser != nil {

        if !ServicesManager.instance().isAuthorized() {
            let user =Storage.sharedInstance.currentUser
            ServicesManager.instance().loginOrSignUp(user) {
                [unowned self] success, error in
                if (success) {
                    self.openMainScreen()
                }
            }
        } else {
            openMainScreen()
        }
    }
```

And loginOrSignUp function is:

```
 func loginOrSignUp(user: QBUUser!, completion: ((success:Bool,  errorMessage: String!) -> Void)!) {

    self.logInWithUser(user) { (success:Bool,  errorMessage: String!) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            Storage.sharedInstance.currentUser = self.currentUser()
            completion(success: success, errorMessage: errorMessage)
        } else {
            self.authService.signUpAndLoginWithUser(user, completion: { (response: QBResponse!, user:  QBUUser!) -> Void in
                if user != nil {
                    Storage.sharedInstance.currentUser = self.currentUser()
                    completion(success: true, errorMessage: errorMessage)
                } else {
                    completion(success: false, errorMessage: response.error?.error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

For example using Parse cloud code I can call function from cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("signUp", function(req, res) {
   var phoneNumber = req.params.phoneNumber;
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo('username', phoneNumber);

    query.find({
      success: function(results) {

        if (results.length > 0) {
            Parse.User.logIn(phoneNumber, secretWord).then(function (user) {
                res.success(user.getSessionToken());
            }, function (err) {
                res.error(err);
            });
        } else {
            var user = new Parse.User();
            user.set("username",phoneNumber);
            user.set("password",secretWord);
            user.setACL({"*": { "read": true }});
            user.signUp(null, {
              success: function(user) {
                    res.success(user.getSessionToken());
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
              },
              error: function(user, error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
              }
            });
        }

      },
      error: function(error) {
        res.error(err);
      }
    });
 });
```

So using Parse I can just login to app with session_token generated with cloud code. 
First question: can I do the same with QuickBlox - use for login some session_token generated in any cloud backend?

And the second question: when user logged in, session is expired in 2 hours and we have to renew session ? 
When user has bad connection, before he receive useful information he has to renew session every 2 hours. Even Ukrainian API for Ukrainian usage (not for for best service in the world) use token generated with login function for any other requests. User should not renew session always - he get only useful information.

But if there is no approach in Quickblox without session renewing, then how to do this renew in right way ? I am very new to iOS development, but when I used Parse, I didi not get this problems (

Comment: Hi! I will answer any QB related question, but it is slightly unclear what do you need. You mean 1. Does QB iOS SDK can be initialized with already generated token? 2. How to handle token expiration?

Comment: Yes, 1) 1. Does QB iOS SDK can be initialized with already generated token? - Parse for example had 'PFUser.becomeInBackground("session-token-here")'. iOS app send only one request to server - 'loginOrSignup' and server make or login either signup and return to app. 2) How to handle token expiration? - if I will handle session expiration in for example 'applicationWillEnterForeground' it will freeze UI until session will checked. If not freeze UI, then errors will arrive. Or should I check session with every request ??